# 407 Proxy Authentication required error in Safari

Tags: safari, http-status-code-407

I have hosted a small application on a server, when I try to access the link from safari it gives me a 407 error. The same link works fine for Chrome and other browsers. can you please point me in right direction?

Comment: Welcome. So, 407 is proxy authentication required. Where has your research led you so far? I see there are some hits on apple discussion forums - worth a look?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, the error was because one of the server was stopped in our webfarm, looks like safari is not good at rerouting the request once it comes across a stopped server, it continues to refer the same or may be the cached data.